# Unknown command line option '-skip'

Tags: android, linux, qt, linux-mint

I'm trying to build `Qt 5.11.1` from source for android using the [guide](http://wiki.qt.io/Android) but it fails at `Preparing build tree`.
The command I use is:

```
../qtbase/configure -prefix /home/user/Qt/5.11.1/android_armv7 -release -xplatform android-g++ --disable-rpath -nomake tests -nomake examples -android-ndk-host linux-x86_64 -android-toolchain-version 4.9 -android-ndk /home/user/source_qt/android-ndk-r10e/ -android-sdk /home/user/Android/Sdk/ -no-warnings-are-errors -skip qttranslations -skip qtserialport -skip qtserialbus -skip qtscxml -skip qtscript -skip qtcharts -skip qt3d -skip qtdatavis3d -skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtgamepad -skip qtvirtualkeyboard -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebsockets -android-arch armeabi-v7a
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Preparing build tree...
<srcbase> = /home/user/source_qt/qtbase 
<bldbase> = /home/user/source_qt/build 
<outbase> = /home/user/source_qt/build 
Creating qmake...
.Done.
ERROR: Unknown command line option '-skip'.
```

The `-skip` part in necessary to exclude components not supported by android, so I'm completely lost to why it says that "-skip is an unknown command".

I'm using `Linux Mint 18.3`
The `NDK` and `SDK` paths should be correct, and my java version is

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

I tried searching for some info about that error, but not much comes up.
If anyone has any idea what could be the cause of that error, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run `configure` from top level of Qt sources and not from qtbase. In other words, you are giving top level configure options to qtbase configure which doesn't recognize them.

Comment: My mistake for not clearing it up. `source_qt` is just a folder I created for organizing my drive, in `qtbase` is the actual source from `git clone` from:`https://github.com/qt/qtbase`.

Comment: In your question you are referring to a guide for building whole Qt but now you are stating you are configuring just qtbase module?

Comment: I see, so I was trying to build the wrong repo the whole time?
I guess this one should be right one then `https://github.com/qt/qt5` ?
I feel so stupid now, thanks.

Comment: See also https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-71253 for discussion of this undocumented behavior